# Upgrading Vagrant in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtual-machine, vagrantfile, apt-get

I currently have **Vagrant 1.8.1** installed in my Ubuntu 16.04

I'm thinking to upgrade it to **Vagrant 2.0.0**

The problem is I'm not sure if my vagrant files and VMs gets removed if I directly install **Vagrant 2.0.0** using apt-get install vagrant.

Is it safe to update using apt-get or is there any way to do that.

Answer (score 21):

Vagrant repository probably not updated to the latest version, this is the reason that it always install older version when `apt-get install vagrant` command is used.

The easiest way to pull and install latest version using terminal is to find the path to the `.deb` file and install it using `dpkg`

You may get the list of all the `vagrant` updates here,

```
https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/
```

I got this as latest version from above archive,

```
https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/2.0.4/vagrant_2.0.4_x86_64.deb
```

Once you have that link, delete previous version of `vagrant` (if it is installed) as follows,

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove vagrant
rm -r ~/.vagrant.d
```

and install newest version,

```
wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/2.0.4/vagrant_2.0.4_x86_64.deb
sudo dpkg -i vagrant_2.0.4_x86_64.deb
```

Once done, you can verify if its successfully installed,

```
vagrant version
```

Comment: in my case this worked without removing the old installation. cheers!

Comment: Following your instruction exactly, it works for me on Ubuntu 16.04 Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

The safest way to upgrade any program, is to use `sudo apt-get upgrade <program name>`. Your files won't be affected

Note that `sudo apt-get install <program name>` will not affect any of your files either.

Comment: Tried doing
**apt-get upgrade vagrant**
**apt-get --only-upgrade vagrant**
**apt-get --only-upgrade vagrant=2.0.0**
**apt-get --only-upgrade install vagrant=2.0.0**
**apt-get install vagrant**

But nothing worked fine. The installed version is still 1.8.1 where as the latest version is 2.0.0 from website.

Comment: I tried to install it myself using `apt-get install vagrand` and also got the version 1.8.1, i think the version 2.0 is not yet available on ubunut's repositories, you sould install it from vagrant's website instead. This - (https://superuser.com/questions/845987/how-do-i-upgrade-vagrant-to-last-version-in-ubuntu/845989) should help

Comment: Yes. thinking to do the same. But will it affect any of my existing VMs or Vagrant files?

Comment: Some newer syntax may not be supported any more in vagrant 2.0. More information here : https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/installation/upgrading.html - But your files won't be removed, for more security, you can copy them in an other directory (located outside vagrant's range)

Answer (score 0):

You can just download the new version from [vagrant official site](https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html)

install it and then try running `vagrant -v` in terminal, if is showing old version or not detecting vagrant run  `sudo dpkg -i vagrant_2.2.9_x86_64.deb` (check your version of vagrant, I have put mine), now run `vagrant -v` again, you should see the new version.